# Cannot copy after making selection with TMUX

Tags: tmux

I can make a selection using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> like so:

[image]

but the problem is that I cannot find the keystroke to copy the selection to the clipboard. I tried [this guide](https://www.rushiagr.com/blog/2016/06/16/everything-you-need-to-know-about-tmux-copy-pasting-ubuntu/) 
but both <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> did not seem to work.

I tried adding this to my `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
bind -t vi-copy w copy-pipe "xclip -sel clip -i"
```

but I got this error when I ran `source-file ~/.tmux.conf`:

> ```
> home/oleg/.tmux.conf:9: usage: bind-key [-cnr] [-T key-table] key command [arguments]
> ```

What is wrong? How to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to use is old. [The changelog](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/master/CHANGES) states that in the version 2.4:

> Key tables have undergone major changes. Mode key tables are no longer
>     separate from the main key tables. All mode key tables have been removed,
>     together with the `-t` flag to `bind-key` and `unbind-key`.
>
> […]
>
> The `emacs-copy` and `vi-copy` tables have been replaced by the `copy-mode` and
>     `copy-mode-vi` tables. Commands are sent using the `-X` and `-N` flags to
>     `send-keys`.

Your command

> ```
> bind -t vi-copy w copy-pipe "xclip -sel clip -i"
> ```

translates to

```
bind -T copy-mode-vi w send-keys -X copy-pipe "xclip -sel clip -i"
```

Note your question mentions <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>, but the command binds just <kbd>w</kbd>. Adjust if needed (use `C-w` or `M-w` instead of sole `w`).

Comment: @OlegzandrDenman Use `C-w` instead of sole `w`.